# Exponential problem in definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s^2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{-(x-m)^2/(2s^2)} \, dx$$

I am stuck at this problem. Please give some hint as how to initiate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Make the change of variable $t = \frac{x - m}{s}$, and use the celebrated Gaussian integral formula:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} dt = \sqrt{2\pi}. \tag{$*$}$$

For a proof for $(*)$, check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) link. Also, the first answer to [this math stack exchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009922/what-are-the-theorems-in-mathematics-which-can-be-proved-using-completely-differ) referred a paper that gives $10$ different ways to prove $(*)$, which is very fun to read.

If you have learned some probability, you may identify this expression as the mean value of normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(m, s^2)$, which is $m$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-(x-m)^2/(2s^2)}\,dx
  =\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-m)e^{-(x-m)^2/(2s^2)}\,dx
    +m\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-m)^2/(2s^2)}\,dx\ .$$